# Expectation value of $1/x$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given a random variable $x$ which is assumed to follow a Gaussian distribution
$x \sim N( \mu, \sigma^2 )$ and $x$ is further known to be positive, I am interested in the following expectation value: $E\left[ \frac{1}{x} \right]$  .

In my case $\mu \gg 0$, which might allow to ignore that $x$ is always positive.

Does anyone knows about a collection of known expectation values under the normal distribution?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ is further known to positive? Is this a truncated normal distribution?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "collection" of expectation values?

Comment: In any case $E[1/x]=\infty$ .

Comment: $\mu\gg0$ makes no sense -- the relevant comparison here would be $\mu\gg\sigma$. Anyway, as Learner said. It doesn't matter how small the density is at $0$; the integral over $1/x$ diverges.

Comment: I do not think, that $E \left[ \frac{1}{x} \right] = \infty$.
If I compute the expectation value by sampling I end up with a reasonable finite value. And yes, it is a truncated normal distribution. Is there an analytic approximation for this integral? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to compute $E(1/|x|)$ by the same sampling method?

Comment: I rejected all $x \leq 0$

Comment: Did you check what happens when you increase the sample size? Did the mean converge?

Comment: Yes, it does. I chose $\mu = 10$ and $\sigma = 1$. $E\left[ \frac{1}{x} \right]$ than converges to 0.1010

Comment: This should be an edit to the question rather than a new answer. But first you'll have to [merge your account](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) with the one that posted the question ([old](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/66400/matthias), [new](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/66401/matthias)).

Comment: *Yes, it does*... [I doubt that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRLNdcmRcFY).

Comment: @Did: I think it might. It seems that Matthias' results match my PV estimates.

Comment: @robjohn How does one define the expectation of a random variable whose neither positive part nor negative part is integrable?

Comment: @Did: I was replying to "I doubt that", which was in response to Matthias saying to joriki that the mean converged. The mean of $\frac1x$ is going to be taken over all samples where $\frac1x$ does not overflow. This leaves out a small, symmetric interval around $x=0$. This corresponds to what happens when taking the principal value integral. The smaller we take the symmetric interval, the closer the expected value comes to $0.10103161564918598872=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}e^{-50}\,\mathrm{erfi}(5\sqrt2)$.

Comment: @robjohn I do not understand "all samples where 1/x does not overflow", you might want to explain. Anyway the maths are clear: any sequence of empirical harmonic means of an i.i.d. sample of x diverges almost surely. Of course if the values in (-a,a) for some positive a are *censored* then the empirical harmonic mean does converge (to a limit which may depend on a). But (1) this statistical procedure has little to do with the original problem and (2) any answer based on it and failing to mention the fact would be misleading, especially in view of some of the OP's  previous reactions.

Comment: @Did: I assume that Matthias is running a computer simulation, and that values too close to $0$ are being rejected since $\frac1x$ overflows. That is, the simulation must be rejecting $x\in[-\delta,\delta]$ for some small $\delta\gt0$. My answer below computes the principal value for the singular integral, which computes the limit of the integral minus $[-\delta,\delta]$ as $\delta\to0$. This is $(2)$. Thus, the PV integral should reflect the results of the simulation. This addresses the results of the simulation (not the original problem), which was the basis of "I doubt that".

Comment: @robjohn Quote: *Did you try to compute E(1/|x|) by the same sampling method? – I rejected all x≤0 – Did you check what happens when you increase the sample size? Did the mean converge? – Yes, it does.* To sum up, the simulation the OP describes does not behave as the OP says. The procedure you mention is interesting but it bears little resemblance to the one-sided rejection algorithm described by the OP (which diverges).

Comment: @Did: "Yes, it does. I chose $\mu = 10$ and $\sigma = 1$. $E\left[ \frac{1}{x} \right]$ than converges to 0.1010" That seems to be the "Yes, it does." to which "*Yes, it does*... [I doubt that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRLNdcmRcFY)." replied.

Comment: @robjohn Of course the "Yes it does" to which "I doubt that" replied is the one saying that E(1/|x|) converges to 0.1010. (The statement "E(1/|x|) converges to 0.1010" itself is absurd but it most probably refers to the (wrong) fact that the empirical mean of an i.i.d. sample distributed like 1/|x| converges (almost surely?) to 0.1010 when the size of the sample converges to infinity.) Since the convergence as described by the OP is wrong, I fail to see the problem you have with "I doubt that".

Comment: @Did: Matthias does not claim that $\mathrm{E}\left(\frac1{|x|}\right)$ converges, he says that his samples (I assume via simulation) indicate that $\mathrm{E}\left(\frac1{x}\right)$ converges (no absolute values). Now, it did bother me that he said he rejected $x<0$. However, I then considered that $\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\lt11356$ where $\epsilon=2^{-16382}$, which is the smallest positive extended precision number, and $e^{-50}\lt2\times10^{-22}$. Thus, the extended precision contribution of the singularity would be less than $1\times10^{-18}$. So much for simulations.

Comment: @Did: I have added a caveat to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

We will use
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2k}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=(2k-1)!!\sqrt\pi\tag{1}
$$
If we take the principal value, we get the convergent series
$$
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{PV}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1xe^{\large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_0^\infty\frac1x\left(e^{\large-\frac{(\mu-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}-e^{\large-\frac{(\mu+x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1x\sinh\left(\frac{\mu x}{\sigma^2}\right)e^{\large-\frac{\mu^2+x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\large-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1x\sinh\left(\frac\mu\sigma x\right)e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=e^{\large-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+1)!}\frac{\mu^{2k+1}}{\sigma^{2k+2}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
We can also get an asymptotic expansion from $(2)$ using stationary phase:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\large-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1x\sinh\left(\frac\mu\sigma x\right)e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac12\left(\frac1{\frac\mu\sigma+x}+\frac1{\frac\mu\sigma-x}\right)e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\mu}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac12\left(\frac1{1+\frac\sigma\mu x}+\frac1{1-\frac\sigma\mu x}\right)e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\sim\frac1\mu\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2k-1)!!\frac{\sigma^{2k}}{\mu^{2k}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
We can get a "closed form" in terms of $\mathrm{erfi}$ from $(2)$
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1x\sinh\left(\alpha x\right)\,e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cosh\left(\alpha x\right)\,e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=e^{\large\frac{\alpha^2}{2}}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1x\sinh\left(\alpha x\right)\,e^{\large-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\alpha e^{\large\frac{t^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\sqrt2}i\int_0^{i\alpha/\sqrt2} e^{\large-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\,\mathrm{erfi}(\alpha/\sqrt2)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
and plugging $(6)$ into $(2)$ yields
$$
\mathrm{PV}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1xe^{\large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\sigma}e^{\large-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}\mathrm{erfi}\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right)\tag{7}
$$

---

**Extended precision is not enough**

It is mentioned in a comment that $x<0$ was rejected. This poses a theoretical problem. The computations above are carried out in principal value, that means that a small interval $[-\delta,\delta]$ is rejected, where $\delta\to0$. However, if $x\lt\delta$ is rejected, then, as $\delta\to0$, the the contribution to expected value from the singularity grows like
$$
-\frac{\log(\delta)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-50}\tag{8}
$$
Even using extended precision, where $\delta=2^{-16382}$, $(8)$ amounts to about $8.74\times10^{-19}$ which is pretty insignificant. However, as $\delta\to0$, $(8)\to\infty$.

Therefore, even extended precision arithmetic is insufficient to expose the problems with a simulation where $x\lt0$ is rejected.